# Why filtering isn't working in React and JS. Help me to find a mistake

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, filter, find

Can not understand why filter is not working.
The function get an object. If there is the same object in the state, the function delete this object from the state. If not, add to the state.
The problem is that the object rewrites the state, but not add it to the state.

For example, **object {a: 1, b: 2}**

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState<any[]>([]);

const addObject = (data) => {
    const sameData = !!products.find((item) => item.id === data.id);
    const deleteData = products.filter((item) => item.id !== data.id);
    const newData = sameData ? deleteData : [...products, data]; 
    return setCheckedRoles(newData);
  };
```

As a result I get not *[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 8, b: 3}];*
but only one object that come to function *[{a: 1, b: 2}]*

Comment: None of your objects have `id` properties so how do you expect it to work?

Comment: yes, it was a mistake. But as it is an example, in real code the object contains id.

Answer (score 0):

You want `deleteData` to run only when `sameData` is true, but instead it is running the moment you're defining it. (remember that `filter()` is being invoked)

To get the expected behaviour move the deleteData to be a function and execute it as per your wish

```js
const [products, setProducts] = useState<any[]>([]);

const deleteData = (products) => products.filter((item) => item.id !== data.id);

const addObject = (data) => {
    const sameData = !!products.find((item) => item.id === data.id);
    const newData = sameData ? deleteData(products) : [...products, data]; 
    return setCheckedRoles(newData);
};
```

Also please find a better name for the function `addObject` :)